# How to prove that $\int_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)u(x) dx \to \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)u(x) dx \ \forall u\in E$ by using a "density argument"?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ denote the space of $C^\infty$ functions with compact support. Let $E$ be an Hilbert space and assume that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $E$.

Take $(f_n)_n\subset E$ be a sequence of functions such that

$$\int_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)\varphi(x) dx \to \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\varphi(x) dx \quad\forall\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R),$$
and $f\in E$.

I need to prove that
$$\int_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)u(x) dx \to \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)u(x) dx \quad\forall u\in E.$$

I asked for help to the lecturer, but he said that it is a "simple density argument".

The question is: what does it mean density argument? Is actually so easy to show the second convergence? I am stuck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that the result holds in full generality (in fact, [there are good reasons to believe it does **not**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100349/weak-convergence-on-a-dense-subset-of-test-functions)), but here is a quick proof (basically Andrew's argument above) under the additional assumptions that :

1. $E$ inherits the norm and inner product from $L^2(\mathbb R)$,
2. the sequence $(f_n)_n$ is uniformly bounded in norm : $\|f_n\|_E\le M $ for some $M>0$.

Let $u\in E$, and let $(u_m)_m$ be a sequence in $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $\|u_m - u \|_E \to 0$ (such a sequence exists by density).

Then we can perform the following decomposition :
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)u(x) dx - \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)u(x) dx\right|&=\left|\int_{\mathbb R} [f_n(x)-f(x)]u(x) dx\right|\\ 
&\le \left|\int_{\mathbb R} [f_n(x)-f(x)]u_m(x) dx\right|+ \left|\int_{\mathbb R} [f_n(x)-f(x)][u(x)-u_m(x)] dx\right|\\
&\le \left|\int_{\mathbb R} [f_n(x)-f(x)]u_m(x) dx\right|+ \|f_n-f\|_E\|u-u_m\|_E\\
&\le \underbrace{\left|\int_{\mathbb R} [f_n(x)-f(x)]u_m(x) dx\right|}_{(A)}+ \underbrace{M'\|u-u_m\|_E}_{(B)}
\end{align}

where $M' :=2\max\{M,\|f\|_E\} $.

Now let $\varepsilon >0$ : by assumption there exists $m\equiv m(\varepsilon)$ such that $\|u-u_m\|_E\le\varepsilon/2M'$, hence for this $m$, the term $(B)$ is smaller than $\varepsilon/2 $. But since $u_m\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, we also have that for large enough $n$ (the threshold depends on $m$), the term $(A)$ is also less than $\varepsilon/2$.

Comment: Stratos supports the strike, could you please provide more details about the fact that also the term (A) is less than $\varepsilon/2$? It is not clear to me.

Comment: Since $u_m\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, we have by the very first assumption that $\int_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)u_m(x) dx \to \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)u_m(x) dx$. This means precisely that
$$\left|\int_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)u_m(x) dx - \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)u_m(x) dx\right|  = \left|\int_{\mathbb R} [f_n(x)-f(x)]u_m(x) dx\right| \to 0$$
As $n\to\infty$. So for large enough $n$, $(A)$ is smaller than $\varepsilon/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $u_n \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ with $u_n\to u$. Then $$|\langle f_n-f,u\rangle| \leq |\langle f_n,u-u_m\rangle|+|\langle f_n-f,u_m\rangle|+|\langle f,u_m-u\rangle|$$
By assumption, $$|\langle f_n-f,u_m\rangle | \underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$
The other two terms vanish as $m\to\infty$ by the Schwarz inequality.

Comment: $\|f_n\|$ may not be bounded though ?

Comment: After using Cauchy-Schwarz, you have $\|f_n\| \|u-u_m\|$. We know $\|u-u_m\|$ can be made small by the choice of $u_m$, but how do we know $\|f_n\|$ remains bounded?

Comment: thanks for the remark, i'll leave it up for now...

Answer (score 1):

Just one additional remark: This is a consequence of a famous theorem from functional analysis (namely, the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, which in fact states a little bit more): If $X,Y$ are Banach spaces and $(T_n)_n\subseteq L(X,Y)$ is a sequence of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$, and $T\in L(X,Y)$ is a bounded linear operator, then the following statements are equivalent:

1. $(T_n)_n$ converges strongly to $T$, i.e., $T_nx\to Tx$ $(n\to \infty)$ for all $x\in X$.
2. $(T_n)_n$ is bounded (i.e. $\sup_{n}\|T_n\|<\infty$) and there exists a dense subset $D\subseteq X$ such that $T_nx\to Tx$ $(n\to \infty)$ for all $x\in D$.

The proof essentially is the same as the proof given in one answer below. In your case, $X=L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $Y=\mathbb{C}$, $T_n(\varphi)=(f_n,\overline{\varphi})_{L^2}$, $T(\varphi)=(f_n,\overline{\varphi})_{L^2}$ for $\varphi\in X$.